Confusion on extending functionals from real vector space to a complex vector space
I'm reading the proof of a lemma saying:
Let $V$ be a normed complex vector space, and denote by $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ the same space regarded as a normal real vector space. The map taking a linear form on $V$ to its real part is a norm preserving bijection $V' \to (V_{\mathbb{R}})'$. (where apostrophe denotes taking the dual)
The proof then goes:
If $z \in V'$ then its real part $x \colon v \mapsto \frac{1}{2} (z(v)+ \overline{z(v)})$ is real-linear and
$$ z(v) = x(v) - ix(iv) , \quad v \in V.$$
Conversely, if $x \in (V_{\mathbb{R}})'$ and $z$ is given by the above, then $z \in V'$ and $\Re (z) = z$.

This last part seems absurd to me. If $x \in (V_{\mathbb{R}})'$ then it is defined on a real vector space, so for example it can only take real coefficients and maps into $\mathbb{R}$. However, how is $x(v)$ then even defined? I am aware that the complexification of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ will be isomorphic to it, so can we just define $x$ as the unique extension under this complexification? I'm not sure what is meant since complexifications have not even been mentioned in this book.
Help in understanding what is going on would be much appreciated!

As you say, if $x \in (V_\mathbb{R})'$, then it is linear for the real numbers. We define an element $z \in V'$ by setting
$$z(v) = x(v) - ix(iv)$$ for $v \in V_\mathbb{R}$. Remember that $V_\mathbb{R}$ is the same set as $V$. We have just changed which scalars we should be able to pull out of linear maps. So both $v$ and $iv$ are still elements in $V_\mathbb{R}$ and it is legitimate to evaluate $x$ in them. What is not legitimate is to say something like $x(iv) = ix(v)$, since $x$ is not complex-linear.

I see. That makes sense. Thank you
